# Issue in print on FF with absolute positioning

Tags: html, firefox, printing, css, css-position

I am facing some issue in printing a form created using absolute positioning in FF. I am printing on A4 sheet. The page comes fine if its single paged form, but when i have to print multi page form the only first page is printed and other elements that have to come on second page overwrites each other in a single line on the next page. Its quite weird the same is working fine on IE

**NOTE** I am unable to share the html as it includes a lot of css and quite complex and big HTML pages.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
@-moz-document url-prefix() {div{position:relative} }
@media print { marquee { -moz-binding: none; } body{overflow:visible !important;} }
#a{
position:absolute;
top:50px;
left:70px;
}
#b{
position:absolute;
top:1050px;
left:170px;
}
#d{
position:absolute;
top:1650px;
left:270px;
}
#c{
position:absolute;
top:1550px;
left:470px;
}

</style>
</head>
<body>asdasd
<div id="a">aa</div>
<div id="d">bb</div>
<div id="b">ff</div>
<div id="c">asd</div>
asdasda
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Cant we do anything like manipulating the html file at back end (servers side) and provide a PDF as output. I tried this but facing challenge in creating multiple pages in PDF too for `position:absolute`

Comment: make a style for "print" and set all div position to relative

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a thread where the topic was already discussed:
[Firefox printing only 1st page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4609007/firefox-printing-only-1st-page)

However, the problem could be in the css.
As explained here http://briancaos.wordpress.com/2008/12/05/firefox-only-prints-first-page-of-contents/

If you have an

```
overflow: hidden;
```

in your css, change it to

```
overflow:visible;
```

and then it should work.

Comment: my page doesnt have any `overflow : hidden;` in case i had something of that kind too i wont mind that portion of page to not be displayed on print out but other stuff should get printed....

Answer (score 1):

There's a long standing issue with Firefox and printing absolute positioned elements as mentioned by Daniele B.

Can you redo the HTML+CSS to use relative positioning?

In the CSS add some page-break stuff (http://davidwalsh.name/css-page-breaks). That should make it easier to style the block elements so they flow in each 'page' and align things correctly when `@media` print.

Comment: relative positioning also has issues... tried it too,.. as soon as i provide `left` and `top` on elements i get print issues

Comment: the link doesnt helps in case of absolute positioning... :S

Answer (score 1):

If it is possible, set the height of the `div` elements.  This will at least force visibility onto two pages.  However, it does not deal with overlapping `div`s, and there still may a problem of visibility of the `div` content.

Here is my revision (some visibility borders and coloring was added, and the `width` may or may not prove useful):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">
    @-moz-document url-prefix() {
        div{
            position:relative;
            background-color: #dddddd;
            border: 1px solid #999999;
            width: 20%;
        } 
    }

    @media print { 
        marquee { 
            -moz-binding: none; 
        } 
        body{
            overflow:visible !important;
        }
    }
    #a{
        position:absolute;
        top:50px;
        left:70px;
        height: 1000px;
    }
    #b{
        position:absolute;
        top:1050px;
        left:170px;
        height: 600px;
    }
    #c{
        position:absolute;
        top:1550px;
        left:470px;
        height: 500px;
    }
    #d{
        position:absolute;
        top:1650px;
        left:270px;
        height: 100px;
    }

</style>
</head>
<body>asdasd
<div id="a">aa</div>
<div id="d">bb</div>
<div id="b">ff</div>
<div id="c">asd</div>
asdasda
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I only use "Print Preview" in FF; I don't have a printer attached to my computer.  PP shows that some of the text dissappears . . . not sure why.

Comment: thats what complete text is not getting in print preview as well

Answer (score 0):

change your position:absolute to position:relative. you can target firefox only in your print stylesheet using: @-moz-document url-prefix() {div{position:relative} }

Comment: still it will give issue the top and left been set will restructure the page... and as soon as we have top and left on page it wont print correctly and will just give 1 page

Comment: though i was conviced it wont work still i gave it a try and it didnt worked

Comment: ok. man this is like a needle in a haystack with no code, but try this: @media print {
 marquee { -moz-binding: none; }
 body{overflow:visible !important;}
}

Comment: the solution been provided didnt helped.. i have edited the question and have provided a sample code...

Comment: my bad man. ok, well add the ids so they override in specificy @-moz-document url-prefix() {div#,div#b,div#c,div#d{position:relative} }  im digging around in firefox here: jar:file:///C:/Program Files %28x86%29/Mozilla Firefox/omni.jar!/chrome/toolkit/res/

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5813/discussion-between-varun-and-albert)

Comment: didnt helped... didnt get the jar part?? what are u trying to do?

Answer (score 0):

```html
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<style type="text/css">

#a{
position:relative;
height:50px;
left:70px;
border:solid 10px blue; 
}
#b{
position:relative;
top:20px;
height:2000px;
left:70px;
border:solid 10px red; 
}
#c{
position:relative;
top:50px;
height:250px;
left:70px;
border:solid 10px purple; 
}
#d{
position:relative;
top:100px;
height:3000px;
left:70px;
border:solid 10px green; 
}

</style>
</head>
<body>asdasd
<div id="a">aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa</div>
<div id="b">bbbbbbbbbb</div>
<div id="c">cccccccccccccc</div>
<div id="d">ddddddddddddd</div>
asdasda
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is add a non-zero top margin to the absolute element container as **David Earl** writes here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=267029