# Printing absolute divs is not working correctly

Tags: firefox, html, printing, absolute

I want to do a print page with absolute divs. It works in Chrome and IE but not working in Firefox. I am testing with print preview. Firefox shows only one page.

```
<div style="position: absolute; top: 1327px; left: 182px; border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 150px; height: 100px;"></div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 2005px; left: 462px; border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 150px; height: 100px;"></div>

<div style="position: absolute; top: 77px; left: 322px; border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0); width: 150px; height: 100px;"></div>
```

How can i solve this problem?

Comment: Why do you need to use absolute divs?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Because my code creates a flow chart with absolute divs. When user click the mouse it creates a new absolute  div at mouse coordinates

Comment: Maybe this helps? [Firefox printing only 1st page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4609007)

Comment: i couldn't find a solution for me it says the problem was fixed in Firefox 3. But i am using Firefox 8 and it gives same error